# javah issue Android Ndk in Linux

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, javah

I am using Ubuntu Linux 32bit system, in terminal it shows no class specified

> sanidhya09@sanidhya09:~/workspace/NdkFooActivity$ javah -jni
>   -classpath adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/platforms/android-4.2/android.jar;bin/classes/
>   -d jni/ com.example.NdkFooactivity Error: no classes specified bash: bin/classes/: Is a directory

even i have tried this

```
sanidhya09@sanidhya09:~/workspace/NdkFooActivity/bin/classes$ javah
-jni -classpath adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/platforms/android-4.2/android.jar; com.example.NdkFooactivity.NdkFooActivity Error: no classes specified com.example.NdkFooactivity.NdkFooActivity: command not found
```

even i tried External tools configuration
where in argument section i wrote

```
-d /home/sanidhya09/workspace/NdkFooActivity/jni -classpath /home/sanidhya09/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/platforms/android-4.2/android.jar:/home/sanidhya09/workspace/NdkFooActivity/bin/classes com.example.NdkFooactivity
```

even in eclipse i get error saying
make:

> [HelloJni] Error 127 HelloJni C/C++ Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sanidhya09@sanidhya09:~/workspace/NdkFooActivity$ javah -jni -classpath bin/classes:~/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/platforms/android-16/android.jar com.example.NdkFooactivity.NdkFooActivity
```

should be fine, assuming your app package is com.example.NdkFooactivity and the class you are interested in is NdkFooActivity.

Note that you must pass the path to `android.jar` you actually used to compile. In my SDK, the directory is called `android-16`, not `android-4.2`. Also, you need to have the `bin/classes` directory in **classpath**. You may need more **jars** in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

But there is one more thing that I would like to add. (And which has taken up most of my morning solving that)

While specifying the classpath = Refrain from using .`/bin/classes:~/ProjectFolder/bin/classes ( the tilde representing the Home directory)`

But use the "../../" to switch directories. For some reason javah doesn't recognizes the tilde operator for the home directory.

Also one other thing if the class has a dependency on other project then you would need that as well in the classpath

```
user@laptop:~/SomeProject javah -classpath ./bin/classes:../<Whereever the path is>/SomeOtherDependentProject:../<Path to android-sdk>/android.jar <Qualified class path>
```